# pass data from JQUERY | AJAX TO HANDLER ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I am uploading files to my app and i'am using ajax & jqyery & handel in asp.net
this my code jqyery

```
$(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('#Button1').click(function ()
            {
                var files = $('#FileUpload1')[0].files;
                if (files.length > 0) {
                    var id = 1;
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'Handler1.ashx',
                        method: 'Post',
                        data: formData,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function () {
                            alert('success');
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            alert(err.error)
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

and this my code in handler c#

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                    string fileName = context.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                    file.SaveAs(fileName);
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is i need to pass a other variable like id from my jquery to handler someone have any suggestion please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the FormData.Append in your javascript

```
formData.append('id', 'test1234');
```

And in your handler access it via Form

```
var otherData = context.Request.Form;
```

Happy coding, cheers!